# How to use GROUP_CONCAT and UNION in single MySQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, union, group-concat

I have 2 tables in my database which are identical in structure but contain different records. Each table has the field 'keywords' which contains comma delimited data.

At the moment, I'm running 2 MySQL queries to get 2 different results which I then merge, using the following MySQL Statements:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(keywords) keywords FROM table1
```

and

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(keywords) keywords FROM table2
```

I'm sure I should be able to get what I need using a single MySQL statement but all of my attempts to use GROUP_CONCAT and UNION have failed.

Thanks for any pointers/help.

Comment: what exactly were those attempts? and how did they fail? would be nice if you'd show your effort and we didn't have to start from zero

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.keywords),',',GROUP_CONCAT(t2.keywords)) keywords FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

If you don't want duplicate values, then it will be like that :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.keywords) FROM (
    SELECT t1.keywords FROM table1 t1
    UNION
    SELECT t2.keywords FROM table1 t2
) t
```

Comment: This is working except that it's adding a lot of duplicates which aren't in the actual database. For example, the keyword "news" is in 2 records, but the above returns it with 24 entries!

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as that:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(keywords) keywords FROM table1
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(keywords) keywords FROM table2
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fbf12/1).

Comment: This was actually what I tried first, but the problem is that it returns 2 rows instead of just the one.

Comment: You get all keywords in one row. Have you checked my fiddle?

Comment: Yes, your fiddle works perfectly but when I run on my actual database, it returns 2 rows for some reason.